# angular - Change column based on dropdown value

Tags: angularjs

I have a table and I'd like one of the columns values to change based on it's header (which will be a select).

In my controller I have:

```
vm.pricing = [
        {
            id: 'price1',
            heading: 'Floor'
        },
        {
            id: 'price2',
            heading: 'Retail'
        }
    ];
```

My table is setup like:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Vendor</td>
        <td>
            <select ng-model="vm.currentPricing"
                    ng-options="p.id as p.heading for p in vm.pricing">
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>{{::vm.machine.vendorNbr}}</td>
        <td>{{vm.machine.price1}}</td>  <-- ****** What should go here?
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Share what you've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass vm.machine to the controller which can use its currentPricing property to return to your code the correct value to render. Or use ng-show on lots of different  objects to turn off the ones which are not relevant

```
<!-- Assuming vm is your controller, a function in it could do the rendering based on currentPricing field -->
<td>{{vm.describePrice(vm.machine)}}</td>
```

Or

```
<td ng-show="vm.currentPricing=='Option1'">{{vm.machine.price1}}</td>
<td ng-show="vm.currentPricing=='Option2'">{{vm.machine.price2}}</td>
```

Comment: Option 1 worked great, for my controller I added:

function describePrice(machine) {
            return  machine[vm.currentPricing];
        }

Answer (score 0):

I think it should look like that

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>{{::vm.machine.vendorNbr}}</td>
        <td>{{vm.currentPricing.heading}}</td>  <-- ****** What should go here?
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming choosing something in dropdown recalculates the price. so given that assumption I would do this:

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <td>Vendor</td>
    <td>
        <select ng-model="vm.currentPricing"
                ng-options="p.id as p.heading for p in vm.pricing">
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>{{::vm.machine.vendorNbr}}</td>
    <td>{{vm.machine.getPrice()}}</td>  
</tr>
</tbody>
```

--- app.js ----

```
app.controller('SomeController',function($scope){
    $scope.machine.getPrice = function(){
        var price = $scope.basePrice * (1 +  $scope.currentPricing); // I don't know how you calc new price
        return price;
}
```

});